# how to exclude JSON-fields in a custom jsonb query with CriteriaBuilder?

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

I am trying to construct a query with CriteriaBuilder for this json:

```
{
a: value1,
b: vsalue2,
c: value3,
d: value4
}
```

to match native query:

```
select field_with_json -c -d from table1 where field_with_json->>a = 'someValue' and field_with_json->>b = 'someValue'
```

I'm struggling to find the way of how to implement the `'-c -d'` part, that is, deleting certain key/value pairs from the end result in CriteriaBuilder. Is it possible at all?

Comment: please check and let me know if the provided solution works or need some improvement

Answer (score 0):

If the column is of `jsonb` type then you can use the minus `(-)` directly:

```
select field_with_json - '{c,d}'::text[] from table1 where field_with_json->>a = 'someValue' and field_with_json->>b = 'someValue'
```

If the column is of varchar/string type then it can be temporally converted to `jsonb` and then keys can be removed:

```
select field_with_json::jsonb - '{c,d}'::text[] from table1 where field_with_json->>a = 'someValue' and field_with_json->>b = 'someValue'
```

As one of the solution provided by `atish.s` you can select and extract specific keys from json

Or we can use the `builder.literal` to build the query.

```java
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<String> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(String.class);
Root<Table1> root = criteriaQuery.from(MyTable.class);
// criteriaQuery.select(builder.literal("field_with_json -c -d"));
criteriaQuery.select(builder.literal("field_with_json - '{c,d}'::text[]"));

// Predicate predicate = builder.and(
//     builder.equal(builder.literal("field_with_json->>a"), builder.literal("someValue")),
//     builder.equal(builder.literal("field_with_json->>b"), builder.literal("someValue"))
// );

Predicate predicate = builder.and(
    builder.literal("field_with_json->>a = 'someValue'"),
    builder.literal("field_with_json->>b = 'someValue'")
);

criteriaQuery.where(predicate);
List<String> fieldsWithJsons = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

For more info check [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)

**Note:** I haven't tested the `CriteriaBuilder` query because I don't have sample data.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the solution, but I wasn't looking for a native query which I already use but rather for the CriteriaBuilder-based solution.

Comment: @Greg have you tried passing the query directly to [`createQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html) it should work.

Comment: no, because I have already a native solution - i wanted a "non-native" query:)

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what the flags `-c -d` are doing, however from my experience with spring and postgres, you can use the following native query to achieve the filtering based on the json field.

```
select field_with_json from table1 where jsonb_extract_path_text(field_with_json, 'a') = 'value1' and jsonb_extract_path_text(field_with_json, 'b') = 'value2';
```

Translating the above into jpa, will result into something like below.

The entity,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
@Data
public class Table1 {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "field_with_data")
    private String fieldWithJson;
}
```

The query,

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<String> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(String.class);
Root<Table1> root = criteriaQuery.from(Table1.class);
criteriaQuery.select(root.get("fieldWithJson"));

Predicate predicate = builder.and(
        builder.equal(
                builder.function("jsonb_extract_path_text",
                        String.class,
                        root.get("fieldWithJson"), // field name in entity
                        builder.literal("a")), // property being targeted in the json object
                "value1"), // value to match
        builder.equal(
                builder.function("jsonb_extract_path_text",
                        String.class,
                        root.get("fieldWithJson"), // field name in entity
                        builder.literal("b")), // property being targeted in the json object
                "value2") // value to match
);

criteriaQuery.where(predicate);

List<String> fieldsWithJsons = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```